# Undefined control sequence \begin{abstract}

Tags: document-classes, abstract

I'm using a CASthesis (not by me) document class to produce my MATH master thesis.

When I compile the file I get an error saying:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \CAST 
                 @label@abstract
l.1 \begin{abstract}
```

However, the PDF actually builds fine, and includes the abstract -  I can successfully run on another computer.

there is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{CASthesis}
\begin{document}
 \begin{abstract}
 hhh
 \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

CASthesis.cls file as follows:

```
%%
%% This is file `CASthesis.cls',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% CASthesis.dtx  (with options: `cls')
%%
%% This is a generated file.
%%
%% Copyright 2004-2006
%% CTEX.ORG and any individual authors listed elsewhere in this file.
%%
%% This file was generated from file(s) of the CASthesis package project.
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.2
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%%
%% This file may only be distributed together with a copy of original
%% source files. You may however distribute original source files
%% without such generated files. Copying of this file is authorized
%% only if either:
%% (1) you make absolutely no changes to your copy, including name; OR
%% (2) if you do make changes, you first rename it to some other name.
%%
%% To produce the documentation run the original source files ending
%% with `.dtx' through LaTeX.
%%
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
%%\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
%%\ProvidesClass{CASthesis}
%% [2011/04/06 v0.2 CASthesis
%%  document class]
\newif\ifCAST@typeinfo \CAST@typeinfotrue
\DeclareOption{notypeinfo}{\CAST@typeinfofalse}
\newif\ifCAST@dvips \CAST@dvipsfalse
\DeclareOption{dvips}{\CAST@dvipstrue}
\DeclareOption{dvipdfm}{\CAST@dvipsfalse}
\DeclareOption{pdftex}{\CAST@dvipsfalse}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{ctexbook}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[cs4size,a4paper,fancyhdr,fntef]{ctexbook}[2005/11/25]

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}    %\baselineskip的倍数，两者相乘为行间距。
\fontsize{12pt}{13pt}\selectfont     %\fontsize{size}{skip}skip相当于\baselineskip
%% check pdfTeX mode
\RequirePackage{ifpdf,ifxetex}
%% math packages
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs,bm}
%% graphics packages
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
%% sort and compress citations
\RequirePackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
%%
%% The tikz package is used for doing the actual drawing.
\RequirePackage{tikz}
%% packages and settings depend on PDF mode
\ifxetex
  \RequirePackage[xetex]{hyperref}
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\else
  \ifpdf   % We're running pdfTeX in PDF mode
    \RequirePackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
  \else    % We're not running pdfTeX, or running pdfTeX in DVI mode
    \ifCAST@dvips
      \RequirePackage[dvips]{hyperref}
      \RequirePackage{psfrag}
      \AtBeginDvi{\special{pdf:tounicode GBK-EUC-UCS2}} % GBK -> Unicode
    \else
      \RequirePackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}
    \fi
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.ps}
  \fi
\fi
\hypersetup{CJKbookmarks,%
       bookmarksnumbered,%
              colorlinks,%
               linkcolor=blue,%
               citecolor=blue,%
              plainpages=false,%
            pdfstartview=FitH}
\AtEndOfPackage{\makeatletter\input{CASthesis.cfg}\makeatother}
\oddsidemargin 0.6 true cm
\if@twoside
  \evensidemargin 0.5 true cm
\else
  \evensidemargin 0.6 true cm
\fi

\topmargin -0.74 true cm
\headheight 0.6 true cm
%\headsep 0.5 true cm
%\topsep 0.7 true cm
\textheight 23.4 true cm
\textwidth 14.8 true cm
\footskip 1.3 true cm
\parskip 0.5ex plus 0.25ex minus 0.25ex

%\textheight 24.62 true cm
%\textwidth 16 true cm
%\headheight 0.8 true cm
%\parskip 0.5ex plus 0.25ex minus 0.25ex


\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.80}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\newcommand\CASTspace{\protect\CTEX@spaceChar\protect\CTEX@spaceChar}
\def\CAST@getfileinfo#1 #2 #3\relax#4\relax{%
  \def\CASTfiledate{#1}%
  \def\CASTfileversion{#2}%
  \def\CASTfileinfo{#3}}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname ver@CASthesis.cls\endcsname\relax
  \edef\reserved@a{\csname ver@ctextemp_CASthesis.cls\endcsname}
\else
  \edef\reserved@a{\csname ver@CASthesis.cls\endcsname}
\fi
\expandafter\CAST@getfileinfo\reserved@a\relax? ? \relax\relax
\def\CAST@underline[#1]#2{%
  \CTEXunderline{\hbox to #1{\hfill#2\hfill}}}
\def\CASTunderline{\@ifnextchar[\CAST@underline\CTEXunderline}
\newcommand\classification[1]{\def\CAST@value@classification{#1}}
\newcommand\confidential[1]{\def\CAST@value@confidential{#1}}
\newcommand\UDC[1]{\def\CAST@value@UDC{#1}}
\newcommand\serialnumber[1]{\def\CAST@value@serialnumber{#1}}
\newcommand\school[1]{\def\CAST@value@school{#1}}
\newcommand\degree[1]{\def\CAST@value@degree{#1}}
\renewcommand\title[2][\CAST@value@title]{%
  \def\CAST@value@title{#2}
  \def\CAST@value@titlemark{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand\author[1]{\def\CAST@value@author{#1}}
\newcommand\advisor[1]{\def\CAST@value@advisor{#1}}
%\newcommand\advisorinstitute[1]{\def\CAST@value@advisorinstitute{#1}}
\newcommand\major[1]{\def\CAST@value@major{#1}}
%\newcommand\submitdate[1]{\def\CAST@value@submitdate{#1}}
%\newcommand\defenddate[1]{\def\CAST@value@defenddate{#1}}
%\newcommand\institute[1]{\def\CAST@value@institute{#1}}
%\newcommand\chairman[1]{\def\CAST@value@chairman{#1}}
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
    \bf\songti\zihao{3} \CAST@value@school \\
      \bf\songti\zihao{1} \CAST@value@degree\CAST@label@thesis\\
      \bf\songti\zihao{4} {(学位研究生)}
    \vskip \stretch{1}
      \bf\songti\zihao{2} {题目：}\CASTunderline{~\CAST@value@title~}

    \vskip \stretch{1}
    \bf\fangsong\zihao{4}
    \def\tabcolsep{1pt}
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{llcrl}
      {作\quad\quad者：} &
      \multicolumn{4}{l}{\CASTunderline[100pt]{\CAST@value@author}}
    \\
      {学科专业：} &
      \CASTunderline[100pt]{\CAST@value@major}
    \\
     {指导教师：} &
      \CASTunderline[100pt]{\CAST@value@advisor}
    \\
    \end{tabular}

\vskip \stretch{0.5}
    \bf\songti\zihao{3}{2021~年~3~月}
  \end{center}

}
\newcommand\englishtitle[1]{\def\CAST@value@englishtitle{#1}}
\newcommand\englishauthor[1]{\def\CAST@value@englishauthor{#1}}
\newcommand\englishadvisor[1]{\def\CAST@value@englishadvisor{#1}}
\newcommand\englishinstitute[1]{\def\CAST@value@englishinstitute{#1}}
\newcommand\englishdate[1]{\def\CAST@value@englishdate{#1}}
\newcommand\englishdegree[1]{\def\CAST@value@englishdegree{#1}}
\newcommand\englishmajor[1]{\def\CAST@value@englishmajor{#1}}
\newcommand\makeenglishtitle{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{20pt}
      \bf\zihao{2} {Title: }\CAST@value@englishtitle
    \vskip \stretch{1.5}
\bf\zihao{3} {By}\\
\bf\zihao{3} \CAST@value@englishauthor
    \vskip \stretch{1.5}

\bf\zihao{3}{Under the Supervision of Associate Professor}\\
\bf\zihao{3}\CAST@value@englishadvisor\\
\vskip \stretch{1.5}

\sf\zihao{3}{A Dissertation Submitted to}\\
\sf\zihao{3}{Northwestern Polytechnical University}
\vskip \stretch{0.5}

\sf\zihao{3} {In partial fulfillment of the requirement}\\
\sf\zihao{3} {For the degree of}\\
\sf\zihao{3} {Master of Philosophy}\\
\sf\zihao{3} {In}\\
\sf\zihao{3} {Operations Research and Cybernetics}
\vskip \stretch{2}

\normalfont\zihao{3} {Xi'an, P. R. China}\\
\normalfont\zihao{3} {March 2021}
\end{center}
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage
  \fi
}

\newenvironment{abstract}
  {\Nchapter{\CAST@label@abstract}}
  {}
\newcommand\keywords[1]{%
  \vspace{2ex}\noindent{\heiti \CAST@label@keywords} #1}
\newenvironment{englishabstract}
  {\Nchapter{\CAST@label@englishabstract}}
  {}
\newcommand\englishkeywords[1]{%
  \vspace{2ex}\noindent{\bf \CAST@label@englishkeywords} #1}


\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \Nchapter{\contentsname}%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
%\addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\CTEX@spaceChar\relax}

\pagenumbering{roman}%-------------------------------
\setcounter{page}{1} %---------------------------------------

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
%-------------------------------------------
\makeatletter %双线页眉
%\topmargin 0.2 true cm
 \def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi%
 \hrule\@height 1pt \@width\headwidth\vskip1pt%上面线为1pt粗
 \hrule\@height 0.5pt\@width\headwidth  %下面0.5pt粗
 \vskip-2\headrulewidth\vskip-1pt}      %两条线的距离1pt
 \vspace{6mm}}     %双线与下面正文之间的垂直间距
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  %\fancyhead[LE]{\small 西北工业大学硕士学位论文}
  %\fancyhead[RE]{\small \CAST@value@titlemark}
  \fancyhead[CE]{\small 西北工业大学硕士学位论文}
  \fancyhead[CO]{\small \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\small  \thepage}
%  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small ~\thepage~}
{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}

\newcommand\Nchapter[1]{%
  \if@mainmatter%
    \@mainmatterfalse%
    \chapter{#1}%
    \@mainmattertrue%
  \else
    \chapter{#1}%
  \fi}
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern 1.5mu\cdot\mkern 1.5mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1
       \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern 1.5mu\cdot\mkern 1.5mu$}
       \hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern 1.5mu\cdot\mkern 1.5mu$}
      \hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\Nchapter{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}

%-------------=====================================================================
\newenvironment{publications}[1]
    {\Nchapter{\CAST@label@publications}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\CAST@label@publications}
              {\MakeUppercase\CAST@label@publications}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `publications' environment}}%
      \endlist}
%----------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{project}[1]
  {\Nchapter{\CAST@label@project}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\CAST@label@project}
              {\MakeUppercase\CAST@label@project}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `project' environment}}%
      \endlist}
%\newenvironment{resume}
%  {\Nchapter{\CAST@label@resume}}
%  {}
%\newenvironment{resumesection}[1]
 % {{\noindent\normalfont\bfseries #1}
  % \list{}{\labelwidth\z@
  %         \leftmargin 2\ccwd}
  % \item\relax}
  %{\endlist}
%\newenvironment{resumelist}[1]
 % {{\noindent\normalfont\bfseries #1}
  % \list{}{\labelwidth\z@
   %        \leftmargin 4\ccwd
   %        \itemindent -2\ccwd
   %        \listparindent\itemindent}
 %  \item\relax}
  %{\endlist}
\renewenvironment{thanks}
  {\Nchapter{\CAST@label@thanks}}
  {}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newtheoremstyle{break}% name
  {}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%      Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}% Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `CASthesis.cls'.
```

CASthesis.cfg as follows:

```
%%
%% This is file `CASthesis.cfg',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% CASthesis.dtx  (with options: `cfg')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright 2004-2006
%% CTEX.ORG and any individual authors listed elsewhere in this file.
%% 
%% This file was generated from file(s) of the CASthesis package project.
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.2
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% This is the configuration file of the CASthesis package with LaTeX2e.
%% 
%%\ProvidesFile{CASthesis.cfg}
%% [2011/04/06 v0.2 CASthesis
%%  configuration file]
%%\ifxetex
%%  \XeTeXinputencoding "GBK"
%%\fi
%%
%% the setup of ctex package
%%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\def\CTEX@contentsname{目\CASTspace 录}
\def\CTEX@listfigurename{插\CASTspace 图}
\def\CTEX@listtablename{表\CASTspace 格}
%%
%% labels in the title page
%%
\def\CAST@label@classification{分类号}
\def\CAST@label@confidential{密级}
\def\CAST@label@UDC{UDC}
\def\CAST@label@serialnumber{编号}
\def\CAST@label@thesis{学位论文}
\def\CAST@label@degree{申请学位级别}
\def\CAST@label@major{学科专业名称}
\def\CAST@label@advisor{指导教师}
%\def\CAST@label@submitdate{论文提交日期}
%\def\CAST@label@defenddate{论文答辩日期}
%\def\CAST@label@institute{培养单位}
 \def\CAST@label@school{学位授予单位}
%\def\CAST@label@chairman{答辩委员会主席}
%%
%% string values filled in the title page
%%
\def\CAST@value@classification{}
\def\CAST@value@confidential{}
\def\CAST@value@UDC{}
\def\CAST@value@serialnumber{}
\def\CAST@value@school{西北工业大学}
\def\CAST@value@degree{硕士}
\def\CAST@value@title{~~~~~（论~文~题~目）~~~~~}
\def\CAST@value@titlemark{\CAST@value@title}
\def\CAST@value@author{（作~者~姓~名）}
%\def\CAST@value@advisorinstitute{（单位）}
\def\CAST@value@major{}
\def\CAST@value@advisor{（姓名、专业技术职务、学位）}
%\def\CAST@value@submitdate{}
%\def\CAST@value@defenddate{}
%\def\CAST@value@institute{西北工业大学理学院}
%\def\CAST@value@chairman{}
%%
%% labels in the english title page
%%
\def\CAST@label@englishadvisor{Supervisor:}
\def\CAST@label@englishstatement{Submitted in total fulfilment
  of the requirements for the degree of \CAST@value@englishdegree \\
  in \CAST@value@englishmajor}
%%
%% string values filled in the english title page
%%
\def\CAST@value@englishtitle{(English Title of Thesis)}
\def\CAST@value@englishauthor{(Author Name)}
\def\CAST@value@englishadvisor{(Supervisor's Name)}
%\def\CAST@value@englishinstitute{(Institute Name)}
\def\CAST@value@englishdate{%
  \ifcase\month\or
    January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
    July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  , \number\year}
\def\CAST@value@englishdegree{Ph.D.}
\def\CAST@value@englishmajor{}
%% labels in the abstracts
\def\CAST@label@abstract{摘\CASTspace 要}
\def\CAST@label@englishabstract{Abstract}
\def\CAST@label@keywords{关键词：}
\def\CAST@label@englishkeywords{Keywords:~}
%%
%% labels in the publications
%%
\def\CAST@label@publications{攻读硕士学位期间完成的学术论文}
%% labels in the project
\def\CAST@label@project{攻读硕士学位期间参加的科研项目}
%%

%% labels in the thanks
%%
\def\CAST@label@thanks{致\CASTspace 谢}
%%
%% the chapter title format
%%
\def\CTEX@chapter@nameformat{\bfseries\heiti\zihao{-3}}
\def\CTEX@chapter@titleformat{\bfseries\heiti\zihao{-3}}
\def\CTEX@chapter@beforeskip{15\p@}
\def\CTEX@chapter@afterskip{12\p@}
%%
%% the section title format
%%
\def\CTEX@section@format{\bfseries\heiti\zihao{4}\centering}
\def\CTEX@section@beforeskip{-3ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
\def\CTEX@section@afterskip{1.0ex \@plus .2ex}
%%
%% the subsection title format
%%
\def\CTEX@subsection@format{\bfseries\heiti\zihao{-4}}

\def\CTEX@subsection@beforeskip{-2.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
\def\CTEX@subsection@afterskip{1.0ex \@plus .2ex}
%%
%% the subsubsection title format
%%
\def\CTEX@subsubsection@format{\bfseries\heiti\zihao{-4}}
\def\CTEX@subsubsection@indent{2\ccwd}
\def\CTEX@subsubsection@beforeskip{-2ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
\def\CTEX@subsubsection@afterskip{1.0ex \@plus .2ex}
%%
%% the theorems definitions
%%
\theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem{algo}{算法~}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{thm}{定理~}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{lem}[thm]{引理~}
  \newtheorem{prop}[thm]{命题~}
  \newtheorem{cor}[thm]{推论~}
  \newtheorem{con}[thm]{猜想~}
 \newtheorem{cla}{断言~}[chapter]

\newtheorem{cons}{构造~} [chapter]
\newtheorem{conc}{结论~} [subsection]

\theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{defi}{定义~}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{conj}{猜想~}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{exmp}{例~}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{obs}{观察~}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{rem}{注~}
  \newtheorem{case}{情形~}
\theoremstyle{break}
  \newtheorem{bthm}[thm]{定理~}
  \newtheorem{blem}[thm]{引理~}
  \newtheorem{bprop}[thm]{命题~}
  \newtheorem{bcor}[thm]{推论~}
 \newtheorem{bcon}[thm]{猜想~}

\renewcommand{\proofname}{\bf 证明}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `CASthesis.cfg'.
```

I have delete the .aux file, it can't work.
I use ctex 2.9.2.164, winedt 10.3

Comment: Is `CASthesis.cls` publicly available somewhere so we can test it? If possible you should create a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) we can copy and paste to test, and replace all the `\include` commands with dummy text, and generally remove calls to files we don't have.

Comment: i create a minimal working example.

Comment: `CASthesis.cls` calls another file `CASthesis.cfg`, and we need that as well to test.

Comment: Where did you get that version of CAthesis.cls (v0.2 dated 2011/04/06)? There appears to be a newer version (v0.3 dated 2016/04/16) at [this github repo](https://github.com/CTeX-DEV/CASthesis). When I use yours with the current version of `ctexbook.cls` on CTAN, I also get an error, but I do not get one with the new version from github. (I installed with `git clone https://github.com/CTeX-DEV/CASthesis.git` then `cd CASthesis` then `latex CASthesis.ins` and it unpacks the `.cls` and `.cfg` files.)

Comment: Thank you! I do it.